# Size of jquery.fn.init changes unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse HTML code in jquery, get an attribute of it and extract a number from the id, and then append it to a string like that:

```
                function sortHTMLContentByStrength(x, y) {
                console.log($($.parseHTML(x)));

                let strength1 = 
                   parseFloat(($("#team-modal-strength-" + $($.parseHTML(x)[1]).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0]).html()));
                let strength2 =
                   parseFloat(($("#team-modal-strength-" + $($.parseHTML(y)[1]).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0]).html()));

                return strength2 - strength1;
            }
```

The real problem is:

[image]

As you can see, i get this `S.fn.init(2)`. Every single console log looks like this. I roughly know what it means and also it wouldn't be a big deal because I used an index to retrieve only the second element (`tr` tag) which I'm interested in like that:

```
$($.parseHTML(x)[1])
```

I'm just getting the second element of the returned array which is tr tag. This code worked and there was nothing wrong with up until now.

So, now the biggest problem. When I run the same code once more later, I don't receive an array of two objects anymore. I get this:

[image]

It's not an array anymore so the indexing trick `$($.parseHTML(x)[1])` doesn't work anymore.
I really need to call this sorting function multiple times in my program but due to the issue the app breaks. I would be very thankful for any hints on that.

Comment: On the first case you received an array with length = 2 containing a `text` and a `tr`. On the second case you are still receiving and array but just with length = 1, which includes only the `tr`.

So you should check what changed in your HTML to obtain that, but a quick solution would be to do `$($.parseHTML(x)[0])` insted of `$($.parseHTML(x)[1])`

Comment: Well, I don't really know what this `text` means and where it comes from. When I expand this, I get: https://imgur.com/a/LwXOhVH .